# How does one query the Global Address Book in Outlook by position title?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm reading a document at work that involves a bunch of position titles, but I don't know who the people actually are, I only know their job titles.

I know this information is available in the Global Address Book, but I don't know how to put in a job title (and I guess location) and get back an actual person's name and contact information.

How is this generally done within an organization?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to search people from GAL via Job title or position?

Normally, we can click Advanced Find to search people by more conditions:

[image]

I found [one TechNet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ded3f102-624b-4212-a0a4-2f5cbd43833f/how-to-search-global-address-book-for-an-email-address?forum=outlook) for your reference.